# how to get a column in CSV file and seperating the text and saving to other column in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, split

for example we have a csv file with

```
name       address           age 
vip     bang #@ india     12 
ags     myso ^% india     25 
dhs     bang #@ india     14 
fgn     nyk  @$ bangla    45
```

how to make this and add to different column

```
name    city     country   age 
vip     bang    india     12 
ags     myso    india     25 
dhs     bang    india     14 
fgn     nyk     bangla    45
```

the code i am using is

```
import re
import csv
with open("/home/vipul/Desktop/example.csv", 'rb') as f:
    mycsv = csv.reader(f)
    for row in mycsv:
        text = row[0]
        txt = re.findall(r'(\w+[\s\w]*)\b', text)  
        print txt
```

Comment: Read the file with a csv reader; split the middle column; write the file back with a csv writer. If it does not work, post your code and ask a specific question.

Comment: while reading its not considering special charecters its treating them as normal characters the code i am using is   `import re
import csv
with open("/home/vipul/Desktop/example.csv", 'rb') as f:
    mycsv = csv.reader(f)
    for row in mycsv:
        text = row[0]
 txt = re.findall(r'(\w+[\s\w]*)\b', text)  
 print txt
 
`

Comment: Please paste your code into the question, do not post it as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["vip", "ags", "dhs", "fgn"],
    "address": ["bang #@ india", "myso ^% india", "bang %@ india", "nyk @$ bangla"],
    "age": [12, 25, 14, 45]
})

# Split "address" string on spaces, keep first split
# as city, last split as country
df["city"] = df["address"].str.split(" ").str[0]
df["country"] = df["address"].str.split(" ").str[-1]

print df
```

Which results in:

```
         address  age name  city country
0  bang #@ india   12  vip  bang   india
1  myso ^% india   25  ags  myso   india
2  bang %@ india   14  dhs  bang   india
3  nyk @$ bangla   45  fgn   nyk  bangla
```

**EDIT:**

Optionally, keep only certain columns:

```
# Optionally, keep only certain columns
df = df[["name", "city", "country", "age"]]
print df
```

Which yields:

```
  name  city country  age
0  vip  bang   india   12
1  ags  myso   india   25
2  dhs  bang   india   14
3  fgn   nyk  bangla   45
```

**EDIT 2:**

You can use pandas to read and write to file, instead of creating the dataframe yourself:

```
# Read the dataframe from file:
df = pd.read_csv("input_file.csv", sep=",")

# Split "address" string on spaces, keep first split
# as city, last split as country
df["city"] = df["address"].str.split(" ").str[0]
df["country"] = df["address"].str.split(" ").str[-1]

# Optionally, keep only certain columns
df = df[["name", "city", "country", "age"]]

# Write altered dataframe to file
df.to_csv("output_file.csv", sep=",", index=False)
```

**EDIT 3:**

As pointed out in the comments, splitting twice is unnecessary; you can do this instead:

```
split = df["address"].str.split(" ")
df["city"] = split.str[0]
df["country"] = split.str[-1]
```

Comment: sir this is in CSV file i need to import and then write onto it !!

Comment: You can use pandas to read the csv file instead of writing the dataframe manually: `df = pd.read_csv("input_file.csv")`, then do the string-splitting as above, then write it to file again: `df.to_csv("output_file", sep=",", index=False)`

Comment: Don't split it twice!  Do it once up front and refer to the result.  `df["address"].str.split(" ")`

Comment: @piRSquared thanks, good point, I'll add an edit.

Comment: what if some of them have 3 things to split   `banglore @# karnataka @#$ india`

Comment: Then a) your provided example input is insufficient and this answer is no longer valid, b) you will probably have to use a regex approach, and c) you have a really, really weird data set.

Comment: Having said that, you can use regex for splitting your with [str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), but since you only have 2 output columns and now 3 input strings, I don't know what you want to do with it.

Comment: thank you so much for the answers !!

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @Plasma i have a error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex2.py", line 7, in <module>
    df["city"] = df["name"].str.split(" ").str[0]
     raise KeyError('no item named %s' % str(item))
KeyError: 'no item named name'`

Comment: @VipulRao sounds like there's no column called `name` your dataframe. You can check with `list(df.columns)`